# Why does converting this react function into a class create these error messages?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/create-a-custom-react-date-picker-in-10-minutes-82fa19775f66) on how to create a datepicker in React/JS, and for the sake of uniformity in my project code, I'd like to use a class definition in my datepicker component. But when I tried converting the 'Final datepicker component' from the tutorial into a class, I received these error messages (there's more messages like this where the variable or callback is undefined, but I'll refrain from post:

```
./src/components/datepicker/datepicker.jsx
  Line 73:13:   'focusedDate' is not defined                no-undef
  Line 74:13:   'isDateFocused' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 75:13:   'isDateSelected' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 76:13:   'isDateHovered' is not defined              no-undef
```

// My datepicker component (this is causing the errors, but if I use the function definition in the tutorial, everything's fine):

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { useDatepicker, START_DATE } from "@datepicker-react/hooks";
import { jsx } from "@emotion/core";
import Month from "./month";
import NavButton from "./nav_button";
import DatepickerContext from "./context";

class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null,
      focusedInput: START_DATE
    });

    const {
      firstDayOfWeek,
      activeMonths,
      isDateSelected,
      isDateHovered,
      isFirstOrLastSelectedDate,
      isDateBlocked,
      isDateFocused,
      focusedDate,
      onDateHover,
      onDateSelect,
      onDateFocus,
      goToPreviousMonths,
      goToNextMonths
    } = useDatepicker({
      startDate: state.startDate,
      endDate: state.endDate,
      focusedInput: state.focusedInput,
      onDatesChange: this.handleDateChange
    });

    this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this);
    this.formatDate = this.formatDate.bind(this);
  }

  handleDateChange(data) {
    if (!data.focusedInput) {
      this.setState({ ...data, focusedInput: START_DATE });
    } else {
      this.setState(data);
    }
  }

  // Formatting date 
  formatDate(date) {
    let splitDate = date.split('/');
    let month = splitDate[0];
    let day = splitDate[1];
    let yr = splitDate[2];

    if (month < 10) {
      month = '0' + month;
    }

    if (day < 10) {
      day = '0' + day;
    }

    return month + '/' + day + '/' + yr;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="calendar-wrapper">
        <DatepickerContext.Provider
          value={{
            focusedDate,
            isDateFocused,
            isDateSelected,
            isDateHovered,
            isDateBlocked,
            isFirstOrLastSelectedDate,
            onDateSelect,
            onDateFocus,
            onDateHover
          }}
        >
        <div>
          <strong>Start date: </strong>
          {state.startDate && formatDate(state.startDate.toLocaleDateString())}
        </div>
        <div>
          <strong>End date: </strong>
          {state.endDate && formatDate(state.endDate.toLocaleDateString())} 
        </div>

        <NavButton onClick={goToPreviousMonths}>Previous</NavButton>
        <NavButton onClick={goToNextMonths}>Next</NavButton>

        <div
          css={{
            display: "grid",
            margin: "32px 0 0",
            gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${activeMonths.length}, 300px)`,
            gridGap: "0 64px"
          }}
        >
          {activeMonths.map(month => (
            <Month
              key={`${month.year}-${month.month}`}
              year={month.year}
              month={month.month}
              firstDayOfWeek={firstDayOfWeek}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        </DatepickerContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Datepicker;

Comment: Because they are only in scope in `constructor`.  You'll need to attach them to the actual Datepicker instance if you want them available in render.  Additionally, you are showing a class based component.  Did you mean to write a function component?  Hooks are only available in function components, not class based.

Comment: Take a closer look at the tutorial, they don't use `class Datepicker extends React.Component {}`.  They just make a function.

Comment: Ahhh I see, so if I want to use hooks, then I have to use function components?

Comment: Correct, in fact hooks are meant to make it such that you don't need to write class components.  Facebook found that there was too much overhead and confusion with writing classes so they made hooks to augment how you write functional components by replicating the beneficial parts of classes.  Hooks are meant to provide lifecycle "hooks" to functional components.  If you are writing classes, you don't use hooks, you use the normal lifecycle hooks built into classes.  If you are writing functional, that's when you use hooks.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the explanation! That makes sense. I have another question related to this code, but I can post a different question if that's better. Essentially, I've changed the start and end date display from plain text to input text fields that autofill based on what dates the user clicks, and now I'd like it so that when the user types a date in the input field, it also updates on the calendar. Right now the user can change the dates, but it doesn't update on the calendar.